# how to write output of one module in another module as csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, export

I am trying to write output of one module in a output file of another module. For example,

first module :

```
def sentence_token():
    
    # some code
    
    sentences = sentence_tokenizer(tokens)
    count_sentence = f"total count of sentence is {len(sentences)}"
```

second module :

```
def word_pos_definition():
    
    # some code
    word_pos_definition_content = []
    with open('get_para_report.csv', 'w') as final_csv_file:
        final_csv_file.write('\n'.join(word_pos_definition_content))
```

I need the `count_sentence` in first module write with `get_para_report.csv` in second module. Anyone have any idea, would help alot. Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by the `count_sentence`, a string, writing "with" a file in another module. can you please explain more?

Comment: if i print ```count_sentence```, i will get result like ```total count of sentence is 4```

Comment: please give an example with variables and the content you want to be written in the file to resolve any ambiguity.

Comment: and I need that ```total count of sentence is 4``` in ```get_para_report.csv```

Comment: so you mean you want it to be written in the csv file instead of being printed have I understood correctly?

Comment: you type faster than me as I get my answers before I ask my question:) got it

Comment: yes, I need the content of ```count_sentence``` from module 1 in the output of module 2 where ```get_para_report.csv``` as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do multiple things to have both values in your CSV file.

1. you can append your data, so the content another file has made doesn't get deleted.

```
def sentence_token():
    
    # some code
    sentences = sentence_tokenizer(tokens)
    count_sentence = len(sentences)}

    with open('file.csv', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(count_sentences)) # a \n might be desired depending on your exact output

def word_pos_definition():
    # some code
    word_pos_definition_content = []

    with open('file.csv', 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(word_pos_definition_content))
```

2. you can `import` any module in another, or maybe a third main module who gets the values from both modules and does the write operation

```py
def sentence_token():
    
    # some code
    
    sentences = sentence_tokenizer(tokens)
    count_sentence = len(sentences)

    return count_sentence
```

```py
import first_module

def word_pos_definition():
    # some code
    word_pos_definition_content = []
    count_sentence = first_module.sentence_token()

    with open('file.csv', 'w') as file:
       file.write((str(count_sentence)+'\n').join(word_pos_definition_content))
```

Comment: thank you :) I tried the first method.